# Background check companies in the US - how much power do they have?

Tags: hiring-process, applications, background-check

When a US citizen applies for a job in the US, and the employer sends their application to a background check company, then if the background check company uses only legal methods, can it just by having the candidate's name, resume (with a list of present and past jobs), SSN, driver's license number **(but without asking the candidate to provide any additional evidence such as paychecks etc)** verify data such as:

1. Is the candidate employed at the moment? If so, who is the current employer?
2. Was the candidate employed by an employer X in the past, and if so during what period?
3. What was the candidate's salary in past and current positions?

What methods do background check companies may use which are illegal?

Do such background check companies have any legal authority to access data that ordinary citizens do not have a legal access to? For example as an ordinary US citizen, even if I had somebody's SSN, I do not know how legally I could use this info to obtain any personal data on that person.

**Let me clarify** that when I apply for a job and my application is sent to a background check, I usually ask the prospective employer not to contact my current employer for any verification, since I want to keep my job search confidential.

Comment: This is like multiple questions in one. Which is your question: *"Do background check companies approach my current employer to verify my employment, title and salary? If not, how can they do that legally? What data are they legally allowed use?"*

Comment: @smci Some of the things they do I already knew about, like calling ex employers and asking about me. I suspect they also look up my SSN at some DBs that would be illegal for me to access. I wanted to know if this is true and if it is legal. Sometimes I give impolite recruiters a fake SSN before I even have a first contact with the employer because they insist the employer "requires" this for getting my resume submitted. I do not give my real SSN to an employer before I get & accept a job offer. When I provide a fake SSN I rarely hear back, but maybe it is because it's just a resume mill scam.

Comment: There are at least ten red flags in that. Never ever provide your SSN to anyone unless and until you have a job offer in writing from a specific named manager at a specific named employer, and you've spoken with them and verified they exist. **Never ever provide your SSN upfront to a recruiter as some bullshit prerequisite for submitting your resume**. That's just asking for identity theft. Also, most quality employers use third-party employment/salary verification, so you provide the SSN to them instead, with a very clear limited-scope agreement about what for.

Comment: As to whether some recruiters have black DBs where they use SSNs in unauthorized ways, that's a secondary issue which you'll avoid by not giving out your SSN in the first place. If you find any evidence of such, report it to the relevant federal agencies. Anyway, it's perfectly possible to do employment/salary/position verification without SSN, with just full name, DOB, position title and dates worked.

Comment: This seems way too broad to me to even attempt a comprehensive answer. Perhaps you should split this up because I see at least 3 different questions and some of those are state-specific as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the candidate employed at the moment? If so, who is the current
>   employer?

In the United states there is no database of employer/employee relationships. The background check company will if tasked to verify all the companies you listed on your resume/application and will contact them.

For large companies they send all the requests for employment verification to a third party who will confirm dates or employment. Therefore the background check company will only be told the dates of employment.

In these cases don't worry about about your current boss being told. These types of checks are also done for loans, apartment leases. I don't think you have something to worry about. But they are professionals and their goal isn't to get you fired.

For smaller companies, the risk is that they will talk to somebody who will tell your current boss.

Now if you told the new company that you aren't employed they will not be able to track down your current employer via a database. If you told them that you are still employed by company X, but you left weeks ago, they will find out because the employment dates won't match.

> Was the candidate employed by an employer X in the past, and if so
>   during what period?

For former employers see the answer above. Of course there is no risk that you can get fired by a former employer.

> What was the candidate's salary in past and current positions?

In the United States employers generally won't give out salary information unless you have specifically directed them to. For all the companies that I have worked for over the last few decades they have implemented a form that you submit that tells your employer to release your salary information.

This is done when the reason for the check is for a loan. Sometimes they contact to make sure that you can afford the new monthly payments. they are also sometimes done when the background check is for a position where financial problems would be a disqualifying factor.

I have never run into a situation where they were collecting salary information to determine their salary offer.

Legitimate companies will provide a document to explain what the background check will consist of. It will specify if there is a criminal component, and if a SSN is needed it will explain why.  These checks are done as a condition of employment, but after the other parts of the offer have been worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Your application undoubtedly contains a list of previous employers and a list of the educational institutions you have attended that the background check company would be able to use to verify that you got the degrees you claim at the institutions you claim and that you worked at the places you claimed on the dates that you claimed.  Any accredited school or moderately sized business is going to be able to confirm things like degrees awarded, job titles, and dates of employment.

If the company does a criminal background check, court records are (generally) public records.

Your application also undoubtedly contains a section where you authorize the background check company to perform a background check.  That section will go into some detail about the specific things you authorize the background check to entail (though that is likely to be overly broad, most companies for most positions are going to focus on a subset of the things that they could investigate).  If, for example, you're applying for a job in a bank, one of the things you'll almost certainly authorize would be for the background check company to pull your credit report.  That's private information that some random person off the street isn't going to be able to access (hopefully) but since you consented they're allowed to access it.

Answer (score 0):

But they don't just have SSN and driver license. They have a resume where you claim work experience and you probably filled out other data to apply.

Most companies will confirm or deny if you were employed.  Say you really did work there you would want them to confirm.

Lot of public data such as court records, lien, and bankruptcy.

Comment: Yes they have my resume with the usual list of past companies. So they simply call the company? Or look up at some DB? BTW I did in the past an experiment - called several past employers, presented myself as a hiring manager, and asked about myself if I was ever an employee there - they refused to tell me.

Comment: I have just clarified in my question that the background check do have my resume. Their mission is of course to verify it.

Comment: They do more than verify a resume and they are professionals at getting information.

Comment: I guess these guys have their methods. I was wondering what they are (in general terms). What you said about court records makes sense, I know it's open to the public (for a certain fee). I am asking about more private data, such as past/current employers and salaries.